# Anti-Aliasing in GPU shader Module(OpenGL)

Tags: python, scripting, opengl

How to smooth the bound of the shape?
If you run the following script in blender,
you can see the Jagged Edge in that shape.

```
import bpy, gpu, bgl
from gpu_extras.batch import batch_for_shader

vertices = [[150, 41.52], [150, 71.52], [56, 234.39],
    [30.0, 249.4], [270, 249.4], [244.02, 234.39]]
indices = ((0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 3), (2, 3, 4), (2, 4, 5), (0, 1, 4), (1, 5, 4))

shader = gpu.shader.from_builtin('2D_UNIFORM_COLOR')
batch = batch_for_shader(shader, 'TRIS', {"pos": vertices}, indices=indices)

def draw():
    # bgl.glHint(bgl.GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT, bgl.GL_NICEST)
    # bgl.glEnable(bgl.GL_BLEND)
    # bgl.glEnable(bgl.GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH)

    shader.bind()
    shader.uniform_float("color", (0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0))
    batch.draw(shader)

bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(draw, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')
```

[image]

So, I try some code to smooth the bound.

```
bgl.glHint(bgl.GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH_HINT, bgl.GL_NICEST)
bgl.glEnable(bgl.GL_BLEND)
bgl.glEnable(bgl.GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH)
```

But it has some gap inside. I am no idea how to fix it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know (and from looking at the docs), I don't see any smoothing options for `gpu` module. Also note that `bgl` is likely to be [deprecated eventually](https://developer.blender.org/T80730).

I know you said you'd rather not, but as my answer, I'd suggest [loading an image](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/gpu.html#d-image). Ideally there would be a way to tint the image within Blender (not sure if that's the case), but if not you can create multiple icons of different colors.

Comment: It's been four years, and there still doesn't seem to be a way to set anti-aliasing with the GPU module. Such a shame...